# How to split the Main title of a plot in 2 or more lines?

Tags: r

Is it possible to split the main title of a plot() in 2 or more lines in R?

Moreover I have a title which consists of many argumenets pasted together

```
plot(1, main=paste("X:",1," ","Y:", 2," ","Z:",3))
```

How can I insert a line break between Y and Z in the main?

Thanks
E.C

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Like this:

```
plot(1)
title(main="This is \nTitle")
```

Edit:

Try this

```
plot(1, main=paste("X:",1," ","Y:", 2," ","\nZ:",3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer indeed this works. I specified my question more to my problem. Would you mind relooking this?

Comment: @ECII jrara has answered your question. Place a `\n` just before the Z, or in the empty space just preceding it.

Answer (score 8):

```
plot(1, main=paste("X:",1," ","Y:", 2," ","\nZ:",3))
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the opposite problem : how to pass from a three line title to a one line title. To solve that, you just add to concatenate your paste vectors as follow:

```
plot(1, main=c(paste("X:",1," ","Y:", 2),paste("Z:",3)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is interesting because it implies another answer to the question that was asked: a length 2 vector will be plotted in separate lines. All the other answers insert a `"\n"` into the string for the line break. I'd recommend editing this answer to address the question asked and point out this new solution! You can leave your "opposite problem" as a footnote.