# How to change the font size in the second main title line of a plot

Tags: r, plot

In addition to this question ([How to split the Main title of a plot in 2 or more lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112786/how-to-split-the-main-title-of-a-plot-in-2-or-more-lines)) I tried to give the second main title line another font size. `cex.main=1` only varies the entire main title.

So I haven’t found anything how it could work…

Has anyone some hints?

Many thanks in advance!

My code:

```
    plot(1, main=paste("X:",1," ","Y:", 2," ","\nZ:",3)) # the “Z: 3” should get a smaller font size
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative to adding second main title and increase font size would be to use `title()` with `plot()`. With `title()` you could also add and manipulate position of "second title" and also font type.

So the code looks like this:

```
    plot(1, main = paste("X:",1," ","Y:", 2," ")) 
   # In order to change font size use cex.main and in order to manipulate 
   # the position of second title use line()
  title(main = ("Z: 3"),  line = 0.5, cex.main = 0.8)
```

And the output (font of Z: 3 is smaller)
[image]